# Replacing NaN values on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, nan

I have a df with some NaN values and I want to replace them with the mean of the values on the adjacents columns (at the same line).

How can I do it?

I'm trying to iterate over all the elements of the dataframe but I'm not going anywhere. Can someone please help me?

Example: in this df, I would like to replace the NaN value with the mean of adjacent columns, the mean between 0 and -2. How can I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [4, 0, 2], 'col2': [1, np.nan, 4], 'col3': [12, -2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.head()
```

Comment: please add sample of dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this would be:

```
mean = df["columnName"].mean()
df["columnName"].fillna(mean,inplace=True)
```

The inplace=True modifies the original dataframe.

EDIT:
For a justification on why to not use inplace=True, you can find it here: [Why You Should Probably Never Use pandas inplace=True](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-probably-never-use-pandas-inplace-true-9f9f211849e4#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20inplace%3DTrue%20keyword,which%20you%20apply%20it%20to.)

Comment: don't use `inplace=True`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with the default linear method:

```
df2 = df.interpolate(axis=1)
```